# Append text to a value in a json arrray

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I append a text to only the first value of an array and send the array back to the server. This is the response i am getting from the server

```
[{
    "12": [ "12", "1", "2", "3" ]
}, {
    "13": [ "13", "1", "2", "3" ]
}, {
    "14": [ "14", "1", "2", "3" ]
}, {
    "15": [ "15", "1", "2", "3" ]
}]
```

I want my array to now be like this so that i can pass this array to my data table.

```
var object = [{
    12: ["12 hrs", "1", "2", "3"]
}, {
    13: ["13 hrs", "1", "2", "3"]
}, {
    14: ["14 hrs", "1", "2", "3"]
}, {
    15: ["15 hrs", "1", "2", "3"]
}]
```

How can I append hrs to the first value?

Comment: not a valid object

Comment: @MoazzamKhan: The JSON is valid; the line starting with `var` is, of course, not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It wasn't valid when he posted that comment - it was the same as in the object declaration :)

Comment: It was, the OP just did not format the last bracket into the object, but it was on the page prior to my edit, I simply formatted it as a part of that code.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed `object` in your question to -

```
var objectArray = [{"12" : ["12", "1", "2", "3"]}, {"13" : ["13", "1", "2", "3"]},{"14" : ["14", "1", "2", "3"]},{"15" : ["15", "1", "2", "3"]}]
```

This is how you can loop through the `objectArray` and change in the way you wanted -

```
for(var i=0;i<objectArray.length;i++)
{
    for(var key in objectArray[i])
    {
        objectArray[i][key][0]+=" hrs";
        break;
    }
}

console.log(objectArray)
```

Comment: object[key][0]+=" hrs"

Comment: @MoazzamKhan: *"I fixed object in your question to"* What you have there is still invalid. You need `:`, not `=`, in the property initializers.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thank you, I fixed it. I did not notice it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hopefully I fixed every thing now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one easy method...

```
// Parse the string response from the server into an object
var obj = JSON.parse(serverResponse);
// loop through the object, knowing that it's nested in the first index of an array "obj[0]"
for(id in obj[0]){
    // obj->arrayIndex->objectProperty->arrayIndex append " hrs"
    obj[0][id][0] += " hrs";
}
// to return this to the server, apply JSON.stringify(obj)
```